# replace \r\n to new line in string with jquery

Tags: javascript

hye, a have a question. 
i used php to save textarea content with new lines (\r\n). when i want to view it back using jquery on the other page. the \r\n also viewed.

for example :
i enter the text

"hai

nama saya sarah"

but when viewed using jquery it become " hai\r\nnama saya sarah"

below is my code :

on script-

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){ 
$.each(value, function(key, value){


var textx = (value.ulasdaftar);
var text = textx.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
 console.log(text);

  $('.sah-body .staff-justifikasi' ).html(text);

   });
  });

 });
```

anyone can help ? thank you

Comment: Why you are replacing dots in text, if you need to replace new line? str.replace(/\r\n/g,'<br>')

Comment: @sinisake I don't think having a string of `'<br/>'` will actually make a break html element

Comment: You might be asking the wrong question. Set `white-space: pre;` (or `pre-wrap`) in CSS if you want `\n` to be rendered as a newline in the browser.

Comment: @paul i've tried but unsuccessful

Comment: @sinisake my code is wrong ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do (obviously it is not replacing of '\r\n' with '<br>')... If answer below didn't solve your problem, please clarify what are your intentions, and provide the rest of code (whole context)

Comment: i want to replace \r\n with new line using jquery.

Comment: @sinisake It might happen that due to for each loop the html is overriding on each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var text = " hye\r\n myname is Sara.";
text = text.replace(/\r\n/g,"<br/>");
para.innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="para"></p>
```

Comment: What is the value of console.log(text) in your code.

Comment: console.text value come from value.ulasdaftar on the above question. the value of ulasdaftar from what user input into the textarea

Comment: You need to post some more code here. So that we can understood your problem.